# Access to files outside of the public folder

Tags: php, forms, security, php-include

For security reasons I want to have all my connection files to the DB and login files in a folder out of the root directory. Like this:

```
Project:
       includes:
            conncect.php
            process_login.php
       general_files:
            index.php
```

In my index.php i have the following.

```
<form action="../includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">
      [...]
</form>
```

The problem is that when i try to submit that form i get an error that says that:

```
 The requested URL /includes/process_login.php was not found on this server.
```

Does anyone knows a way to do what i want to do?

Comment: You can't traverse outside the document root with an HTTP request. You can via `include()` and other file operations.

Comment: FYI your file `conncect.php` has a typo.

Answer (score 3):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778843/better-security-of-php-by-keeping-include-files-outside-the-public-folder): "to be safe, you should move the include files outside document root, thus making it impossible for the web server to serve them directly."
However, to access them, you can use a full path, like so:

```
include('/home/xx/xx/domains/mydomain/webroot/file-to-include.php');
```

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550471/php-include-file-in-webroot-from-file-outside-webroot).

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your document root is `<Project>/general_files`, and if that's the case, then your `process_login.php` file is outside of the public web folder.

You have two options:

1) Move `process_login.php` to the `general_files/` directory and update the `action` attribute accordingly:

```
Project:
   includes:
        conncect.php
   general_files:
        index.php
        process_login.php
```

2) Or add a new PHP file (e.g., `new_login.php`) to `general_files/` that includes `process_login.php`, and set your form's `action` attribute to this file:

```
Project:
   includes:
        conncect.php
        process_login.php
   general_files:
        index.php
        new_login.php
```